# Should I call `delwin(WINDOW*)` that is returned from `initscr()`?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, ncurses

So I came accross [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32410125/6037931) (might not be related) while learning how to use ncurses. I am curious how the ncurses manages its memory, I ran my program under `valgrind` to see how much memory that is used while using ncurses from calling `initscr()` until `endwin()` is called, from this code below in C

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// A program to move to some position(y, x) with
// 0 to LINES - 1 and 0 to COLS - 1
// and tell the user to input something.
// It ends inputting something until user presses
// ESC button.

int c;              // the char
int main()  
{
    initscr(); // this is the first thing to run if you're using ncurses.

    nonl();          // tells the ncurses not to put newline after printing something.
    cbreak();        // no waiting for newline to be inputted. (raw mode)
    echo();          // echo characters.
    
    for( ; ; ) {
        int y = rand() % LINES; // get random value from 0 to LINES - 1.
        int x = rand() % COLS;  // get random value from 0 to COLS - 1.
        move(y, x);             // move cursor to (y, x).
        c = getch();            // to get character
        if (c == 27) break;     // if the user pressed ESC (27)
        // refresh();              // refresh the window to get update.
                                // i realized that it doesn't need to refresh
                                // since the input is already put into the WINDOW
    }
    
    endwin();                   // end session of the ncurses window
                                // also restores the state of the terminal.
}
```

that is compiled with this command `gcc -g file.c -lncurses` and ran (inputted 3 'a's) under `valgrind ./a.out` telling that `valgrind` found some reachable memory leaks as shown below:

```
==30413== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30413== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30413== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30413== Command: ./a.out
==30413== 
==30413== 
==30413== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30413==     in use at exit: 42,466 bytes in 105 blocks
==30413==   total heap usage: 115 allocs, 10 frees, 51,457 bytes allocated
==30413== 
==30413== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30413==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30413==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30413==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30413==    still reachable: 42,466 bytes in 105 blocks
==30413==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30413== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==30413== 
==30413== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==30413== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The similar code that I work from (by adding `delwin()` that returned from `initscr()`) and ran under `valgrind` shows less reachable memory leaks. The code below

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// A program to move to some position(y, x) with
// 0 to LINES - 1 and 0 to COLS - 1
// and tell the user to input something.
// It ends inputting something until user presses
// ESC button.

int c;              // the char
WINDOW* win;        // a pointer to a WINDOW (not neccessary, i guess)
int main()  
{
    win = initscr(); // this is the first thing to run if you're using ncurses.

    nonl();          // tells the ncurses not to put newline after printing something.
    cbreak();        // no waiting for newline to be inputted. (raw mode)
    echo();          // echo characters.
    
    for( ; ; ) {
        int y = rand() % LINES; // get random value from 0 to LINES - 1.
        int x = rand() % COLS;  // get random value from 0 to COLS - 1.
        move(y, x);             // move cursor to (y, x).
        c = getch();            // to get character
        if (c == 27) break;     // if the user pressed ESC (27)
        // refresh();              // refresh the window to get update.
                                // i realized that it doesn't need to refresh
                                // since the input is already put into the WINDOW
    }
    delwin(win);                // deletes and frees WINDOW ????????
    endwin();                   // end session of the ncurses window
                                // also restores the state of the terminal.
}
```

that ran under `valgrind` shows this output:

```
==30798== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30798== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30798== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30798== Command: ./a.out
==30798== 
==30798== 
==30798== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30798==     in use at exit: 34,298 bytes in 79 blocks
==30798==   total heap usage: 115 allocs, 36 frees, 51,457 bytes allocated
==30798== 
==30798== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30798==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30798==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30798==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30798==    still reachable: 34,298 bytes in 79 blocks
==30798==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30798== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==30798== 
==30798== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==30798== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

My conclusion is using `delwin()` that is returned by `initscr()` would make less leak. Should we really take care with the initialized `WINDOW` from `initscr()` too? Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: My experience is that reports of memory "leaks" from ncurses -- at least, some versions -- is something we have to live with. ncurses is not particularly rigorous about cleaning up long-lived memory structures. These "leaks" are probably harmless, but they make using valgrind more difficult.

Comment: @KevinBoone I see. I also found that ncurses can actually "prevent" kinds of memory leaks but it is not available by default and it should be rebuilt by using `--disable-leaks` option to have those(`_nc_freeall()` and `nc_free_and_exit()`) functions exists. But I don't want myself "messing up" something -- ended up with unusable ncurses.

Comment: The referenced question already answers the on-topic part of this question.  For the rest, someone might want to write a tutorial (but that's off-topic).  OP can answer the question best by reading the source-code to understand why delwin won't help.